# how to traverse all the value of input inside a table(html/javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

my html code is like that:

```
<table>
<input type="text" name="FirstInput">
....
<input type="text" name="LastInput">
</table>
```

my question is that, how could I traverse all the input? In fact what I want is to verify whether all the input are empty, I think if I can just traverse all the input then it is possible to do that. But how could I traverse all the value of input inside a table? Thank you very much

Comment: [`for (const elem in document.querySelectorAll('table input')) { console.log (elem); ... }`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: thank you naomik, but could you please explain more in detail? thank you

Comment: what is "table input", do you  mean i should add an id for the table? thank you

Comment: Read documentation of querySelectorAll(): [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: Table input is a DOM query selector. It means any input in any table (its css like syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. If you want to put `input` under `table`, you should do it correctly.

```
<table>
  <input>
  <input>
</table>
```

That code will be *parsed* by the browser like this.

```
<input>
<input>
<table>
</table>
```

```js
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const columns = document.querySelectorAll('#form table tbody tr td input');
  const inputs = Array.from(columns)
    .filter(elm => elm.name !== '')
    .reduce((acc, cur) => ({ ...acc, [cur.name]: cur.value }), {});
    
  console.log(inputs);
    
  return false;
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <!-- ... -->
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input name="fullname" placeholder="fullname" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input name="username" placeholder="username" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input name="email" placeholder="email" type="email"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="submit"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

Comment: thank you very much. but the problem is i dont want to read allelements in one form. i want only parts of input inside a table. thank you very much

Comment: @martinwang1985 Edited. We need to use `table` element correctly.